# how to fetch only one message by one user

Tags: php, mysql

What's the best way with PHP to read a single record from a MySQL database?

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE receiver ='$id' ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

It is displaying all messages and I want only one post by one user.

Comment: Just a side note - if `$id` is passed directly by user (from form, url...), don't forgot to escape it to avoid SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1):

Use LIMIT

```
"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE receiver ='$id' ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: den it will fetch only one row. i want one row form one user

Comment: User Group By, like this "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE receiver ='$id' ORDER BY datetime DESC GROUP BY receiver"

Answer (score 1):

`Limit` will do it.You can use either

```
"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE receiver ='$id' ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1"
```

Or you can like

```
"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE receiver ='$id' ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 0,1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LIMIT in your query:

```
"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE receiver ='$id' ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1"
```